# creating new workbook in a private sub worksheet_selectionchange

Tags: excel, vba

Good day,

I'm having a problem 'runtime error 1004' adding a new workbook using a private sub. Ideally, my code below will run the macro whenever I select any cell in B2:B49999. I have to copy the visible data (once filtered) from A1 to Z last row and paste it to a NEW WORKBOOK. Please help me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B49999")) Is Nothing Then
srcLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("A1:Z" & srcLastRow, Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Rng.Copy
End If
Workbooks.Add

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, it would be much better if you'd `Dim` your variables in the beginning. Also I didn't understand why you have to add a workbook each time you click on a different cell... but maybe you forgot to include the `Workbooks.Add`in the `If`.
Now, to answer your question, can you please be more specific?
Your code "as is" works to me.

Comment: @Noldor130884 

Hi Noldor! What variables should I put a Dim in the beginning? 
I've to add workbook everytime I click a cell then it will copy all visible cells starting from Range A1 up to last used range and copy to a new workbook.

Every code lines are working starting from If to End If. Whenever I put 'workbooks.add' in between if, it will post run time error 28, out of stack space. Still directs me to an error.

The real question is, how could I add a new workbook, copy all the visible data (whenever it is filtered) and paste in the new workbook.

Comment: _What variables should I declare?_ : All variables you use! (specifically `srcLastRow`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stumbled upton what apears to me to be a bug.

With an AutoFilter active on the sheet, `Target` returns the wrong range: actually all the filtered visible cells (rather than the expect selected range).  This also only seems to occur if the line

```
If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B49999")) Is Nothing Then
```

is present in the code!  In combination with the `Intersect` command the apears to cause the out of stack space error.

As a work-around, try rewriting your test to achieve the same results.  I tried

```
With Target
    If .Column = 2 And .Row >= 2 And .Row <= 49999 Then
```

BTW, your line

```
Set Rng = Range("A1:Z" & srcLastRow, Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

makes no sence to me.

Suggest you try

```
srcLastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Me.Range("A1:Z" & srcLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

BTW2, you should use a `Workbook` variable to refer to the created new workbook, rather than relying on it becoming active.  And be specific on where you paste, eg

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Rng.Copy wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
```

[Tested in Excel 2010]

Comment: I think he filters by hiding the cells he doesn't want.
Also, I don't believe he needs a variable for a workbook considering that he needs only a copy-paste and nothing else...
Finally, when you create a new workbook, if the intersect target range is not specified, the new workbook will trigger that event too.

Comment: @Noldor130884  
You got my point. Whenever I filter all data, then whenever I select a filtered visible row in column B, then macros will run.
You almost got it! It will copy the visible filtered data however, it doesn't allow me to add additional codes after **The_End**. Whenever I add codes after that, it just opens a new workbook without copying any data.

Comment: @Noldor130884  
It will always skip the codes even with your revision. That's weird that just a simple Range("A1").Select will give the code an error that it would go directly to error handler 'The_End'.

Could it be that the new workbook opened is not the active workbook?  Chris is right that there seems to be a bug with intersecting target?

Comment: You could of course use the the first part of his code to prevent a bug in case there is one. What to him doesn't make sense, it does to me, and if you google the piece of code, you will find out that a lot of people do that.
Let me know if with `With Target If .Column = 2 And .Row >= 2 And .Row <= 49999 Then` your bug disappears

Comment: After Chris' last piece of code, I added **End If** then **End With** to run the code. His and yours do the same result. The problem occurs after **End With**. 

>End With
>''''Enter the code below NOT WORKING!
>Range("A1").Select
>Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
>Application.CutCopyMode = False
>Selection.Cut
>Range("A6").Select
>ActiveSheet.Paste

**Thanks for advice of my piece of code. That's far as what I know, or I've searched.**

Comment: FYI, I have to seperate my codes by >. Four indent spaces is not working for me to create code blocks.

Comment: @Noldor130884
I prefer using Chris' code. The difference from your code is that when playing your code, it just keeps going back to first line of code WHENEVER I filter the target range. I replaced workbook.add and Dim a variable as workbook. It always reset resets in line **Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")**.
However in Chris' codes, I was able to run all codes smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Rng As Range
Dim srcLastRow As Integer

    On Error GoTo The_End ' This prevents a new Workbook to be opened while the the first copy is made

    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B49999")) Is Nothing Then

        srcLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range("A1:Z" & srcLastRow)
        Workbooks.Add
        Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

        Set Rng = Nothing

    End If

' Insert here some other code. In case you can use The_End as an error handler. Don't forget then to set your variables to Nothing if you have to.

End

The_End:

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Chris and Noldor,
I'm trying to use Chris' code adding some stuff. After his last code, I added some stuff and put Dim WB as Workbook.

   End If
    End With
    
    With WB
        Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cut
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    End With

Same result with your code Noldor that it gets an error 1004 PasteMethod.
What I'm thinking here is that, private sub worksheet_selectionchange does allow you to create a new workbook, however it doesn't allow you to activate it? Since it does not allow me to paste in the 'ActiveCell'.

Comment: Does this 'ActiveCell' refers to the ActiveCell of the workbook,worksheet of private sub?

Comment: an ActiveCell addresses always the activecell of an **activated worksheet**. But I didn't understand a single thing of your comment before :'D
If you think that the selectionchange is the problem use a flag! Once the selection has been made - flag up - create workbook - do stuff - flag down - ready for another selection.
Would be cool if you could post your final code which gave errors

Comment: Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: Why does my code shows as comments not codes even though I indent four spaces? (T.T)

Comment: Use these ` to include your code between them. Now, your code has one thing that should be banned from your memory :D First of all don't use Select. You should also always try to address the worksheet you want to use, when you select a range without doing so, the code will mostly get one on the wrong sheet. Can you edit your question posting your complete code?

Comment: **Please bear with my codes for a while. I'm trying my best to avoid the Select syntax. I polish my codes after every experience I've gained. I just started macros 2 months ago**

Comment: No problem. But again, can you please provide an updated code?

Comment: I understood your problem: when you `.select` a cell you trigger again the Subroutine